# PCH being ignored when added to existing tvOS project

Tags: xcode, tvos, precompiled-headers, pch

My problem is that I am trying to add a PCH file to an existing tvOS project but it is not taken into consideration and I can't find any resolution to this issue or at least why it is happening.

I've stripped the project to a bare minimum and created a public git repository with the problem here: https://github.com/atomul/PCH_Test

When building, I noticed that the build steps is missing the "Precompile PrefixHeader.pch" step ("ProcessPCH .......") that should happen before compiling the sources, so it seems it doesn't even know it should do it or for some reason it ignores it.

- the prefix header is called "PrefixHeader.pch" and is located in the same directory as the xcodeproj.
- Prefix Header (GCC_PREFIX_HEADER) path is set as "${PROJECT_DIR}/PrefixHeader.pch"
- Precompile Prefix Header (GCC_PRECOMPILE_PREFIX_HEADER) is set to "Yes"
- It happens both in Xcode Version "8.3.2 (8E2002)" and "9.1 (9B55)"
- It happens on macOS Sierra 10.12.5 and macOS High Sierra (10.13) on different computers
- I've tried creating a new project from scratch with the same usage and it worked
- I've tried setting the build settings of the newly created project to the existing project with no success (same for deployment target)
- I have looked through other stackoverflow questions and answers / google but couldn't find the issue
- I've tried cleaning / changing derived date, cleaning build
- I've tried adding PCH file to an existing iOS project and it worked
- This problem happend with 2 different projects